# What organism is this? Repetitive, long thread, double spikes, ... (from a human sputum sample)

Tags: species-identification, microbiology, taxonomy, mycology, species

[Link to video](https://youtu.be/9SH-kQZJHw4)

[image: Photo of it]

Collected in Portugal.

Comment: Welcome  André. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. Enjoy the site. I don't know about anyone else, but I'm not convinced that it's an organism. Did you ask the person what they'd eaten recently? Could you give us some idea of scale (how big)?

Comment: Thank you! The small cells you see next to it are neutrophils. So, it's thin but quite long. Goes on and on, coils, etc. And the double spikes repeat along the way. And it has that darker, nucleus-like, area near the level of the spikes. It must be a living organism or something made by one.

Comment: Why's this off-topic?